# Creating DOM table rows then inserting for efficiency

Tags: javascript, dom, hta

I am trying to convert some work programs into an HTA from excel so I can take advantage of the browser GUI and the speed of javascript compared to VBA. My first test though is to append a table in my HTML. However, doing about 1000 rows seems to take about 30 seconds which seems like a lot considering it causes my HTA browser window to go to not responding for the 30 seconds. From my research on here it seems I need to do the row creations then append the table all at once to reduce the amount of reflows to the DOM. I am having trouble doing that. Here is the code I have so far:

```
function myFunction() {
var today = new Date();
var t0 =  today.getSeconds();
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

var connectionstring="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=dbPATH\\test.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Persist Security Info=False;Mode=Share Exclusive;"

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM TABLE1", connection);
rs.MoveFirst

while(!rs.eof)
{
    var row = table.insertRow(1);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = rs.fields(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = rs.fields(2);
    cell3.innerHTML = rs.fields(3);
    rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close; 
var today2 = new Date();
var t1 =  today2.getSeconds();
alert(t1-t0);
}
```

*Edit:
I figured I would try updating my code to now only appending the DOM once but my code still takes way to long that it not responds but I think its a little bit better. I know it cant be the cycling through the ado because if I only loop through and do not try to write anything to the screen the program finishes creating the htmlSTR variable in less than a second. So its the .after which is too slow.

```
function myFunction() {
var today = new Date();
var t0 =  today.getSeconds();
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var htmlSTR;
var connectionstring="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=dbPATH\\test.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Persist Security Info=False;Mode=Share Exclusive;"

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM TABLE1", connection);
rs.MoveFirst

while(!rs.eof)
{
htmlSTR = htmlSTR + '<tr><td>' + rs.fields(1) + '</td>'
    + '<td>' + rs.fields(2) + '</td>'
    + '<td>' + rs.fields(3) + '</td></tr>'
rs.movenext;
}

$('#myTable tr:last').after(htmlSTR);


rs.close;
connection.close; 
var today2 = new Date();
var t1 =  today2.getSeconds();
alert(t1-t0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my understanding, the actual problem might be the query rather than the DOM manipulation.

An alternate elegant solution would be to employ [`GetString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getstring-method-ado) which shall eliminates the while loop altogether;

```
recordset.GetString(,,"</td><td>","</td></tr><tr><td>","&nbsp;");
```

Comment: I did a test and the ado connection connects and pulls the data almost instant unless you are referring to the ado recordset field method combined with the looping. Il give that method a try. Is there a DoEvents type command similar to vba where you can put it in a loop to stop the not responding issue and let the browser know its not erroring but just taking a while?

Comment: Getstring does not seem to work with hta files. Do you have any other solutions that can help reduce the not responding and speed this up?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840753/using-getstring-in-a-hta-file

Comment: Yea that is my post. We we're able to get it to work!

Comment: it was quicker for sure but for loading 15k rows it was still way to slow. I ended up switching to using Jquery datatables and using pagination with deferred rendering. Cut the load times to a more manageable time. Your response though is the best non jquery method in my opinion.