# Using getstring in a hta file

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, ado, hta

I have a hta file which connects to a database via ADO and then prints to a table. However my code triggers a syntax error at the getstring line and a object does support property or method 'write' error at the document.write section of the code for the table. I am struggling to figure out how to use this getstring method as from my understanding it should be the most efficient way to print out the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>ARMS Hamburger Site</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>


<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="w3-center w3-light-grey w3-padding-32">
<button">Try it</button>

<script language="javascript">
var today = new Date();
var t0 =  today.getSeconds();
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

var connectionstring="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source=\\\\drivepath\\blah\\filedatabase.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Engine 
Type=5;Persist Security Info=False;Mode=Share Exclusive;"

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
var str=rs.GetString(,,"</td><td>","</td></tr><tr><td>"," ");

rs.close;
connection.close; 
var today2 = new Date();
var t1 =  today2.getSeconds();
alert(t1-t0);
</script>

<center>
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td><script language="javascript">document.Write(str)</script></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
<br>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JS is case-sensitive, should be `document.write(str);`. Also, isn't `MoveFirst` a method? It should be called like `rs.MoveFirst()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right about the document.write(str) however, my getstring line still indicates a syntax error. any ideas?

Comment: Newer IEs don't accept empty members in the argument list of the function call. I'äm not familiar with ADODB, but you could try to pass `null` or `undefined`for optional arguments, or pass all the needed arguments. Also please add the exact error message to the post.

Comment: Teemu you are a genius. I put in the 2 for the parameter and then the second parameter rs.RecordCount and it works. Null and undefined did not work and drew a type mismatch error.